# SAS identify when value has changed (within the group) over time and record the balance of each change

Tags: sas, grouping

I have a dataset that holds a time series of customer balances and payment timing detail (late/on-time). I want to identify each instance of when timing for a given customer has changed (switched from late to on-time and opposite) and record associated balance at the point when that change occurred.

I've searched for solution for hours and I'm really stuck with this so your advice would be is much appreciated.

```
data have;
input customer date payment_status $ balance;
cards;
1 201601 on_time 80
1 201602 on_time 70
1 201603 late 60
1 201604 late 60
1 201605 on_time 50
1 201606 on_time 40
1 201607 late 40
2 201603 late 120
2 201604 on_time 100
2 201605 on_time 80
2 201606 late 60
3 201606 late 200
3 201607 late 190
3 201608 late 180
3 201609 on_time 170
3 201610 on_time 160
3 201611 on_time 150
3 201612 on_time 140
4 201603 late 80
4 201604 late 50
4 201605 late 20
;run;
```

Ultimately I would like the output would look like below, so that balance as well as change of payment_status for each of the customer is recorded in new columns.

Please notice that first instance of a customer is not recorded in new variables (VAR1_STATUS_CHANGE & VAR2_BAL_AT_CHANGE) - only when original status has changed in comparison to the original value that trigers input into new vars.

[output_dataset](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xGN0V.png)

```
customer  date  payment_status  balance VAR1_STATUS_CHANGE  VAR2_BAL_AT_CHANGE
1     201601    on_time         80                          .
1     201602    on_time         70                          .
1     201603    late            60      late                60
1     201604    late            60                          .
1     201605    on_time         50      on_time             50
1     201606    on_time         40                          .
1     201607    late            40      late                40
2     201603    late            120                         .
2     201604    on_time         100     on_time             100
2     201605    on_time         80                          .
2     201606    late            60      late                60
3     201606    late            200                         .
3     201607    late            190                         .
3     201608    late            180                         .
3     201609    on_time         170     on_time             170
3     201610    on_time         160                         .
3     201611    on_time         150                         .
3     201612    on_time         140                         .
4     201603    late            80                          .
4     201604    late            50                          .
4     201605    late            20                          .
```

I have tried using first. approach but can't get my 'by' groupings in the order that would provide the answer I'm looking for. Would it perhaps need a separate data step beforehand.

```
proc sort data=have;
    by customer payment_status;
run;

data want;
    set have;
    by customer payment_status;
        if first.payment_status then VAR1_STATUS_CHANGE = payment_status;
        if first.payment_status then VAR2_BAL_AT_CHANGE = balance;
run;

proc sort data=want;
    by customer date payment_status;
run;
```

I wonder if there is a quick way to get that resolved. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Please add what approach (code) you have tried to the question. Seeing how you approached the problem will help others help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're very close with your answer, but it needs a few tweaks.

Firstly, sort by customer and date to get the data in the correct order.  The subsequent data step has the correct `by` variables, but you need to add the `notsorted` option to avoid an error with payment_status not being sorted.

I've added the condition `and not first.customer` to the `if` statement so that it doesn't populate the first record for a given customer.

I've used a `do` statement which avoids having to repeat the `if` condition.

You now don't need your 2nd `proc sort` as the data is in the correct order.

```
data have;
input customer date payment_status $ balance;
cards;
1 201601 on_time 80
1 201602 on_time 70
1 201603 late 60
1 201604 late 60
1 201605 on_time 50
1 201606 on_time 40
1 201607 late 40
2 201603 late 120
2 201604 on_time 100
2 201605 on_time 80
2 201606 late 60
3 201606 late 200
3 201607 late 190
3 201608 late 180
3 201609 on_time 170
3 201610 on_time 160
3 201611 on_time 150
3 201612 on_time 140
4 201603 late 80
4 201604 late 50
4 201605 late 20
;
run;

proc sort data=have;
    by customer date;
run;

data want;
    set have;
    by customer payment_status notsorted;
        if first.payment_status and not first.customer then do;
            VAR1_STATUS_CHANGE = payment_status;
            VAR2_BAL_AT_CHANGE = balance;
            end;
run;
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a perfect answer Longfish.  `notsorted` option does the job!